Facebook Graph API Video Monetization
Is there a way to set the monetization of a video when it is posted via the Facebook Graph API?
When I post the video to Facebook I would like to selectively enable or disable monetization depending on the video.
Monetization requirements have been met and monetization has been turned on in the Meta Business Manager for the Facebook Page.
I am using the {pageId}/videos endpoint.
I have tried setting unpublished_content_type = ADS_POST with scheduled_publish_time set to 10 minutes in the future  and published = false but the post failed.
